# Data binding issue with knockout and revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having trouble getting data binding to work with Knockout when using revealing module pattern.

my javascript is like this

```
var HMS = HMS || {};

$(function () {

    HMS.PatientModel = function () {
        this.Patient_Name = ko.observable();
        this.Patient_Address = ko.observable();
    };

    HMS.PatientViewModel = function () {
        var patient = ko.observable(),
        loadPatient = function () {
            patient = new HMS.PatientModel();
            patient.Patient_Name("Premkumar");
        };
        return {
            patient: patient,
            loadPatient: loadPatient
        };
    } ();

    HMS.PatientViewModel.loadPatient();
    ko.applyBindings(HMS.PatientViewModel);

});
```

I am unable to get the data binding to work with patient name properly. The HTML div tag has `data-bind="text:patient.Patient_Name"`.

Please refer to the code in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stprem/pp9ym/1/.  I would appreciate if you could tell me what I am doing wrong in data binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `loadPatient` function you are replacing the `patient` variable with a new object, but your module already returned a reference to the original observable.  So, updating it in this way will not update what the object returned.

Here is an option: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/pp9ym/6/

Basically, you keep `patient` as an observable and then update it in your `loadPatient` function.  In your view, using the `with` binding can help you protect against your object being null, in case you want to load it after you call `ko.applyBindings`.

Comment: Tx a lot for your help, it works fine now.  I understood the first part of your answer, but for the HTML part I am not very clear why I will not be able to set text using patient.Patient_Name.

Comment: You can as long as your data is loaded before applying bindings.  I just wanted to demonstrate that using the `with` binding will let you bind against your empty observable, then fill it later.  Just an option, if you are loading your data from the server (after applying bindings).